# Select certain records and add them to a queue table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table (Table1) that stores several snapshots for each account. Every day we may receive/Insert new snapshots to the accounts if values change for any of the columns val1, val2, val3, val4, val5

Table1

```
T1ID    Account#    snapshotDate    val1    val2    val3    val4    val5
1       1001        1/1/2017        1111    2222    3333    4224    5551
2       1001        1/1/2018        1111    2222    3333    4444    5551
3       1001        1/1/2019        1111    2222    3333    4444    5550
4       2002        1/1/2017        123     1234    12345   123456  3434
5       2002        1/1/2018        123     1212    12345   123456  3434
6       2002        1/2/2019        333     1212    62626   252525  3434
```

I want to pull from Table1 the updated snapshots for these accounts every week and add them to a table/Queue (Table2) only if it is the first snapshot or if certain columns change (val2 or val5)

Table2

```
T2ID    T1ID
01      1
02      3
03      4
04      5
```

- T1ID 1 for account# 1001 was added because it’s the first snapshot
- T1ID 2 for account# 1001 was NOT added because no change to columns (val2 or val5)
- T1ID 3 for account# 1001 was added because of the change to column (val5)
- T1ID 4 for account# 2002 was added because it’s the first snapshot
- T1ID 5 for account# 2002 was added because of the change to column (val2)
- T1ID 6 for account# 2002 was NOT added because no change to columns (val2 or val5)

Table2 will be used as a queue of changes for each account that will be sent to another process.

What is the best optimized query that I can use for this?

Comment: Indeed, don't ask for the "best optimized query".  Try to make something work first.  Then ask for ideas to improve it.

Comment: Sorry My question is how to implement it? I need some ideas on how to do it?

Comment: Why there is no record for T1ID 6 ?

Comment: Because no change to columns (val2 or val5)

Comment: "I need some ideas" - you start with building a simple query that pulls some data and adding some conditions that narrows it down. You look at loads of example on the internet (there are many). Then when you get stuck you ask for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `LAG()` and `ROW_NUMBER()`.

In a subquery, you can recover the last value for each of the 2 columns to compare withing account partitions, ordered by date. Then, the outer query can bring in the first record in each group, along with the records where any of the 2 related  values changed.

```
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY t1id) t2id,
    t1id
FROM (
    SELECT
        t.*,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [Account#] ORDER BY snapshotDate) rn,
        LAG(val2) OVER(PARTITION BY [Account#] ORDER BY snapshotDate) lval2,
        LAG(val5) OVER(PARTITION BY [Account#] ORDER BY snapshotDate) lval5
    FROM mytable t
) x
WHERE 
    rn = 1
    OR NOT (val2 = lval2)
    OR NOT (val5 = lval5)
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9f111d2ec40ecf254dd2e87c207d6a2c)**:

```
t2id | t1id
:--- | ---:
1    |    1
2    |    3
3    |    4
4    |    5
```